# NSManagedObject category doesn't call awakeFromSnapshotEvents:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a category (Unit+LD) on my custom subclass of NSManagedObject (Unit). I want to fire notifications when an instance changes based on Undo or Redo activity, so I overrode like so in Unit+LD.m:

```
- (void)awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags
{
NSLog(@"awakeFromSnapshotEvents");
[super awakeFromSnapshotEvents:flags];

switch (flags) {
    case NSSnapshotEventUndoDeletion:
        NSLog(@"awakeFromSnapshotEvents: undoDeletion");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:OBJECT_CREATED object:self];
        break;

    case NSSnapshotEventUndoInsertion:
        NSLog(@"awakeFromSnapshotEvents: undoInsertion");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:OBJECT_DELETED object:self];
        break;

    case NSSnapshotEventUndoUpdate:
        NSLog(@"awakeFromSnapshotEvents: undoUpdate");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:OBJECT_CREATED object:self];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Unfortunately, this never gets called. None of the NSLogs I added ever show up, not even the first line of the method. Do I have to register for these notifications somewhere? I thought this method was called automatically...I even tried adding it directly to my Core-Data-generated Unit.m subclass, and it still doesn't work. Did something change in iOS 8?

Thanks! I'm totally stumped on this.

**UPDATE**

There was just a disconnect in how I was assigning the NSUndoManager to the context. Nothing terribly mysterious. Oh well!